# jasmine node testin child process callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have an async function that returns a callback with a status code and path if successful.  I would like to use jasmine to test that I receive that status code and have the path be assigned to all future tests.  I keep getting an undefined value for my tests...

```
function make_valid(cb){
    var vdt = child.spawn('node', base,
        {cwd: ims_working_dir, stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']},
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('spawn error: ' + error);
            }
        });
    vdt.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    vdt.stdout.on('data', function(data) {});

    vdt.on('close', function(code) {

        if (code === 0) {
            cb(null, '/home/');
        } else {
            cb(null, code);
        }
    });
}

describe("IMS", function(cb) {
    var path;
    jasmine.getEnv().defaultTimeoutInterval = 40000;

    beforeEach(function(done, cb) {
        console.log('Before Each');
        path = make_valid(cb);
        done();
    });

    it("path should not be null", function() {
        expect(path).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Here is the output:

```
Failures:

  1) IMS path should not be null
   Message:
     Expected undefined to be defined.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected undefined to be defined.
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/evang/Dev/dataanalytics/IMS_Tester/spec/ims-spec.js:46:16)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

Finished in 0.014 seconds

1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped
```

If i get the path passed in the beforeEach declaration I want to write more tests where I parse the file. I think I am dealing with the callbacks incorrectly or maybe I need to use a spy.  Let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `path` with the return value of the `make_valid` function, yet that function returns nothing.

When I've used `jasmine`, I had success with the `done()` callbacks only for the tests themselves (the `it()` functions).

When needing an asynchronous function before each test, I used  their `runs()` and `waitsFor()` functions.

Try some code like this (modified for your example):

```
var code = null;
beforeEach( function() {
  // get a token so we can do test cases. async so use jasmine's async support
  runs( function() {
    make_valid( function( error, returnCode ) {
      if( error ) code = "ERROR_CODE";
      else code = returnCode;
    } );
  } );

  waitsFor( function() {
    return code !== null;
  } );

  runs( function() {
    expect( code ).toBeDefined();
  } );
} );

afterEach( function() {
  code = null;
} );
```

**EDIT**:
Based on our comments, a suggested approach for a one-time asynchronous test that applies to other tests down the line would be this `sample-spec.js`. The inner tests will not pass if the outer `it()` does not use `done()`.

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";

describe( "The full, outer test", function() {

  var code = null;
  it( "should setup for each inner test", function(done) {
    make_valid( function( error, returnCode ) {
      expect( returnCode ).toBeDefined();
      code = returnCode;
      done();
    } );
  } );

  describe( "The inner tests", function() {
    it( "inner test1", function() {
      expect( code ).not.toBeNull();
    } );
    it( "inner test2", function() {
      expect( code ).toBe(200);
    } );
  } );
} );

function make_valid( callback ) {
  setTimeout( function(){ callback( null, 200 ); }, 500 );
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use runs and waitsFor even with jasmine 2.0? I read that those methods are deprecated. This the doc I'm referring to [link](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node#async-tests)

Comment: Actually, what would you do if you want to run the async functions only once for test.  can you use the done() method?

Comment: The `done()` method is just for tests, I think. You might try a nested `describe()` with an outer `it()` to only run an async setup function once, saving the resulting variable inside the outer-most `describe()`

Comment: Would you have it run as beforeEach in the parent describe? If so, that runs the code on all child describes.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can choose it as the answer if it works for you ; )

Comment: If i make the first it set the global var, i can run the other tests.  Does making a child describe() prevent the children from running if the parent fails?

Comment: @Ptrkcon jasmine will continue if an `it()` test fails, including the inner `describe()`. I am not sure about jasmine's execution order in general, and if everything will happen sequentially. Some test frameworks do not guarantee that, and conventional wisdom says tests should be written without too many dependencies in execution order. Which is why `beforeAll()` and `beforeEach()` type methods exist, to ensure the sequence to the test framework, rather than leave it up to "chance" (it's not really chance ; )